# Dungeons and Dragons Lords of Waterdeep: Which piece is the Ambassador and which the Lieutenant?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

There are two special Agent-like pieces in *Lords of Waterdeep*: the Ambassador, obtained temporarily by assigning an agent to the Palace of Waterdeep, and the Lieutenant, obtained permanently by completing the quest *Recruit Lieutenant*.

In the box, there are two pieces clearly meant to be used to represent the Ambassador and the Lieutenant. One of them is a yellowish-white and the other appears to be unpainted light brown wood.

Is there any canon on which one of these is supposed to be the Lieutenant and which is supposed to be the Ambassador? As far as I have seen, there is nothing in the rulebook specifiying this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the bottom of page 4 of the rulebook, it's indicated that the Ambassador is represented by the yellowish-white piece and the Lieutenant by the unpainted, brown, wooden piece, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Ack, I can't believe I missed this in the rulebook. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem - obviously it's good if you can check thoroughly before asking a question, but I'm glad I could help.